# Oil pressure inside copper tube?

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-transfer, pressure

**Background **

I'm struggling finding how to calculate the pressure that occurs within my system and then once calculated I need to reduce that pressure.

**My system**

I have a 1 inch copper pipe that is 9 inches long.  Inside that pipe I have a 3/4" heating element designed for heating liquids with heat transfer oil surrounding it and threaded into the 1 inch pipe.  My desired temperature is about 450 degrees F. The system is a closed system and the fluid isn't moving so of course as I heat the oil up, pressure will increase.

**Questions**

Will soldered copper connections handle this pressure?  Is there a way to calculate the maximum pressure at 450 degrees F?  I believe once I know that, a pressure relief valve should help with this problem?

Thanks for the help and feel free to ask clarification questions.

Comment: For the copper, oil and heating element you can get the corfficient of expansion per degree change in temperature  - once you have that you work out the changes in volume etc.